# Get the user details from MS Graph and show it in navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I'm trying to show the current logged in user in navbar "Name , profile photo and phone number".
in Home controller i used this to get the details

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
        {
            try
            {
                var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
                ViewData["Me"] = me;
                // Get user photo
                using (var photoStream = await 
              _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync())
                {
                    byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                    ViewData["Photo"] = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                ViewData["Photo"] = null;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Then pass the data to _loginPartial by ViewData, but when i navigate to another page the details on _loginPartial navbar disappear and only show when i call the home controller again

```
 @var user = ViewData["me"] as Microsoft.Graph.User;
 @if (User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
{           

            <li class="nav-item">
                @if(user != null){
                    <span class="navbar-text text"> Hello @user.DisplayName!</span>
                    <span class="navbar-text text"> @user.BusinessPhones.FirstOrDefault()</span>  
                }
            </li>
            if (ViewData["photo"] != null)
                    {
                    <img style="margin: 5px 0; width: 50px; border-radius:50%;" 
                     src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @ViewData["photo"]" />   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <img style="margin: 5px 0; width: 50px; border-radius:50%;" 
                     src="~/img/defaultprofileicon.jpg" />
                    }
```

Is there any way to get user details on Program.cs as i use .net core mvc 6 and share this details across the app so they will appear in navbar in every page, Thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when i navigate to another page the details on _loginPartial
> navbar disappear

Below is a demo to use  `session` to pass the string to appear in navbar in every page ,  you can refer to it.

1.Register `IHttpContextAccessor` and `session` in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
app.UseSession();
```

2.In the controller, set a session variable:

```
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("Photo", "p1");
```

3.2.In _loginPartial.cshtml, inject `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation and use it to get the HttpContext and Session object from that.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
...
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Photo")
```

result:
[image]

Comment: hello Qing Guo, Great idea , i tried and it's work but when i tested to deploy the app on iis server i got an error "HTTP error 500" after the session timeout expires so i had to refresh the page many times to get the home page work again , any idea about that , should i extend the session timeout period or what , thanks for your help.

Comment: @Junior.netare Maybe  you can try to extend the session timeout period. If you have the error after deploying the app on iis server, you can post a new question to descibe the problem clearly  , so that we can help you. If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.